# Why can't I reuse the name of a dynamically-allocated array after I delete it in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, redefinition

So, I was giving some examples of how to use dynamically-allocated 2d arrays and was about to send code that was essentially the following:

```
int size = 5;
int* arr = new int[ size ];
for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    arr[ i ] = i;
delete[] arr;

size = 10;
int* arr = new int[ size ];
for( int i = size; i > 0; i-- )
    arr[ i ] = i;
delete[] arr;
```

This gave me a redefinition error, but I thought that delete[] frees the space in memory (and thus 'arr'). I know how to work around this (new array name, don't delete[]/redefine), but I was wondering what's actually going on that gives the error?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with dynamically allocated arrays. It is the same as this: `int n = 42; int n = 42;`

Comment: Note that you _could_ have reused variable names if the bottom five lines of code had been inside a `{`..`}` block.

Comment: Are you used to working with a language where you can redefine variables like that? If so, which?

Comment: @MrLister:  If you are used to a language where variables "just appear", then you might have learnt parrot fashion that `int arr = new int[size];` is how to create a `size` element array - without having realized the difference between variable definition, initialization, and assignment.

Comment: Others have answered why this doesn't work as a normal scoping problem that you might have in any language.  But I think your questions also reveals a misunderstanding of C++ and why it totally different from scripting languages like for example javascript.  In a scripting language, the symbol for a variable exists at runtime, so it makes sense that you could delete the symbol.  But with C++, the symbols do not actually exist in the program, they are just a sort of annotation so a human can read the source.  So _the very idea of deleting a symbol is misguided_.

Comment: I would avoid the use of naked `new` like this.  Much better to use `std::vector<int> arr(size);` ...  `arr.clear(); arr.resize(size)`;  Or even better `std::vector<int> arr; arr.reserve(size); for(...) arr.push_back(i);`

Comment: `delete` does not remove or undefine a variable. It's impossible to undefine a variable. `delete[] arr` only deletes the memory to which `arr` points.

Answer (score 9):

You might want to try this:

```
int size = 5;
int* arr = new int[ size ];
for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    arr[ i ] = i;
delete[] arr;

size = 10;
arr = new int[ size ]; //<-- no int* here, we just need to reassign
for( int i = size; i > 0; i-- )
    arr[ i ] = i;
delete[] arr;
```

We are indeed deallocating the block of memory arr points to, but that doesn't mean we are removing the int* arr. We just removed it's 'content'.

It's just a non assigned pointer again after we delete it.

Answer (score 2):

The `arr` is declared twice. You can reuse it but without declare it again.

```
size = 10;
int* arr = new int[ size ];
```